# ¿Cómo crear carpetas en un repositorio de GitHub sin usar Git?

Tags: github

En el directorio raíz de mi repositorio sólo me aparecen las opciones de **create new file, upload files, find file.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al momento de subir los archivos tampoco veo alguna opción de crear una carpeta o algo parecido, los archivos se suben directamente a la carpeta raíz del repositorio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo crear una carpeta y subir ahí mis archivos?

Comment: igual va a usar git la unica diferencia es el entorno grafico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas hacer el commit de los que subirás, si solo deseas generar la carpeta, crea la en tu escritorio y arrastra la, luego señalas el titulo del **commit** y su descripción.

Espero mi respuesta te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Recuerda que github funciona como repositorio para proyectos, con un VCS (control de versiones) por lo cual es necesario hacer commit y explicar brevemente cuales fueron los cambios realizados. No confundirlo con una nube como Dropbox o GDrive, saludos.

Answer (score 8):

Solo tienes que hacer clic en el botón <kbd>Créate new file</kbd> y escribir **la ruta completa del archivo que quieres crear**.

Todo el proceso en 6 sencillos pasos:

1. Hacer clic en el botón <kbd>Créate new file</kbd>
2. En la caja de texto que aparece escribir el nombre del directorio que se va a crear. Ejemplo, escribir `docs`.
3. Oprimir la tecla <kbd>/</kbd>, automáticamente, el nombre escrito en el punto anterior se convierte en directorio a aparece una nueva caja de texto.
4. Seguir escribiendo la ruta. Los directorios  **deben** terminar con <kbd>/</kbd>.
5. Escribir el nombre de un archivo (sin terminación en <kbd>/</kbd>) para crear toda la ruta.
6. Hacer *commit* en el archivo.

> ### Notas
>
> - Git es un sistema de control de versiones de **archivos**. Los directorios no son archivos, por lo tanto, los directorios vacíos no necesitan controlarse.
> - Se crearán todos los directorios intermedios que formen parte de **la ruta de un archivo**, pero de nuevo, solo tienen sentido porque forman parte de la ruta del archivo controlado, no porque sean controlados dichos subdirectorios.
> - Si lo que se desea es **preservar la estructura de directorios de un proyecto** es una buena práctica colocar en los directorios un archivo llamado `.gitkeep`, pero este nombre ***es solo una convención***. El nombre puede ser cualquiera. El nombre puede ser, por ejemplo, `.conservar`. Lo importante es que **sea un archivo** *aunque esté vacío*. El punto es una convención para que sea un archivo oculto en sistemas tipo *nix.
> - El punto anterior **funciona en cualquier sistema Git**, no solo en GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguente

```
mkdir prueba

cd prueba

git clone https://web_del_proyecto.git .  
-> Te lo bajas en tu pc al directorio que acabas de crear y que estás dentro

mkdir "mi_nuevo_directorio_con_o_sin_contenido"  -> debe de estar dentro del directorio 
anterior para que el próximo comando no dé error

git add "mi_nuevo_directorio_con_o_sin_contenido"

git commit -m "Nuevo directorio"

git push origin
```

Comandos útiles:

```
git log --oneline tenemos el último cambio
git status
```

Comment: Bienvenido!! gracias por la respuesta. mira por favor [answer]